# Rabbits teaching its own friends to drink from drinking bottle

Tags: training, rabbits

I have 3 bunnies, I've successfully trained one bunny of mine to drink from drinking bottle, but the others weren't able to do so. Do you think that success one could teach its friends to drink like the way she does? Like naturally? Or I should teach those two with the same method? Thank you.

Comment: Related question [Can rabbits drink from a bowl of water?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2354/)

Comment: Can you expand on the rabbits not being able to drink from the bottle? I assume you are using a standard rabbit water bottle with a metal nipple from the feed/pet store. How do you have it set up? How far is the nipple from the bottom of the cage? If they are not drinking from the bottle, how do they get fluids?

Comment: VTC OP has not returned, more info required for complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a comment asking for clarification before addressing how to teach them to drink from the bottle.

From your description it sounds like the 3 rabbits are in separate areas.  If that is the case I would not put them together so they can teach each other. Our existing question [Introducing male rabbit to girl rabbit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10449) addresses some of the challenges on placing rabbits together. Even if they are sibling who have been separated for sometime, it can be bad.  [Rabbits are very territorial](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/514) and are prone to fight each other when one is placed in the others territory.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the bottle and hold it over their heads twice a for a minute every day and they will drink from it and eventually and they won't need you. I didn't even train mine they just noticed that  their water was gone so they drank from the bottle. They will be fine because its instinct to get water.