# Unsuccessful rabbit mating

Tags: rabbits, breeding

One of my does pulled fur and built some sort of nest. Its been 13 days but no litter yet. What is the reason for this?

Another doe isn't always willing to lift her tail. She has bred before but I don't know what her problem is. I am tired of giving it a try.

I keep both buck and doe in separate hutches/cages. I am into serious hobby-breeding because I love the newborn babies.

Comment: Could you describe how you keep the rabbits? Also, what's your background for breeding? Do you just want a litter, are you into serious hobby-breeding, or do you want to go commercial?

Comment: How do I keep ? I keep both buck and doe in separate hutches/cages.
I am into serious hobby-breeding coz I love the newborn babies and sometimes I gift them to my friends who promise to keep good care of them.
Btw how are these question related to my question ?

Comment: I was asking because I wanted to gauge your expereince in breeding, and because the way rabbits are kept can sometimes have an effect on phantom pregnancies. Also, I fully admit if this was a breeding-setup to make money, I would have hesitated to check out my sources about the issues. Actual answers coming in now :).

Comment: 13 Days? You know rabbit gestation is 28 days, right?

Comment: @Layna: What is wrong if someone has setup for making money ?
I can see alot of channel on youtube those doe the farming.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: Its been 13 days she built a nest. And they usually make nest on 14-15 days of pregnancy.

Comment: @Waquas: It is just a personal preference, really. I have no issue with people making money, but I have come to vastly prefer hobby-breeding-setups when it comes to getting healthy pets. Commercial breeding all too often sacrifices the animals health.  In my case, it is guinea-pigs I keep but do not breed myself. The most healthy ones always came from hobby-breeders. Even rescues that usually resulted from accidental breeding usually are healthy and long-lived. It was only guinea-pigs from commercial breeders that developed health-issues early on.

Comment: Advise on how to set up a healthy commercial breeding would be vastly outside the scope of an answer and my experience, though. I only know hobby-breeders for small pets more closely.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  How many days has it been since the doe was breed by the buck?

Comment: @JamesJenkins, I left her with the buck for few days then after some days when I saw her struggling to make nest. I separated the buck.  And its been more than 13 days since she built the nest but no babies yet.

Comment: Please read https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/pet-rabbits-double-pregnacies-and-keeping-the-buck-in-with-the-doe/6586#6586 Please do more research before attempting an further breeding events.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about rabbits as pets. It has become clear from discussions in comments that primary question this OP is asking is in regards to increasing production of baby rabbits without regard for the health and well being of the parents. This is a site for questions about caring for pets.

Comment: I guess you are not here to help rather discourage the people who seeks advice..

Comment: The link you are refering again and agian says itself. That it is necessary to remove buck prior to birth of new kits. But I have removed even 15 days before. So pardon me you, yourself aren't clear on what you are saying. 
I asked you a question above and instead of helping you are discouraging the community.
If you can't help then let anyone who is expert. Please.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here we go:

About your first rabbit, building a newst: As always, you should consult a vet, as this is a medical matter, but it does sound a lot like a [False pregnacny](http://wabbitwiki.com/wiki/False_pregnancy)
It basically makes your doe act as if she was pregnant, even if she is not. It it can even happen for females that are kept alone, but nearness of a buck, mating that does not cause actual pregnancy and basically anything that the does body interprets as sexual activity can promote it happening. It usually passes all by itself, but if it doesn't, you will need to check with your vet what he suggests.

About the second rabbit: Sometimes, rabbits just don't want to mate. It happens, possibly especially in pet-breeds (I have no sources that compare the willingness to mate between wild, domestic and pet rabbits, so it just is reported more and more openly for pet breeds).
Sometimes, the time of the year, the weather, the temperature, everythign that would affect our mood as well, may be an influence, but that could be anecdotical as well. But you may want to keep an eye on that second doe as well. If it shoes an otehr unusualy behavior, have a vet check her over. I woudl think it unlikely she's got a medical problem, though; just a mood-one.

Comment: Really don't know @lyana how It can be possible. One doe looked more than pregnant with belly swelled and its been more than 30 days now and still no baby. Also when I left her with a male she accepted her for mating. I mean if she was pregnant would she have accepted ?

Comment: 30 days of swollen belly and no baby? Get that doe to the vet ASAP! This DOES sound like it may be a more serious medical issue.

Comment: Yeah not sure now if she was actually pregnant..

Answer (score 1):

In your comments [you say "I left her with the buck for few days then after some days when I saw her struggling to make nest. I separated the buck."](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18685/unsuccessful-rabbit-mating#comment24911_18685)

Per ["Pet Rabbits, Double Pregnacies, and Keeping the Buck in with the Doe"](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/pet-rabbits-double-pregnacies-and-keeping-the-buck-in-with-the-doe/6586#6586) leaving the buck in with the doe for more then the couple of minutes it takes for the first mounting to occur, is very counter productive.

Double pregnancies, absorbing and/or aborting pregnancies, [life threatening depression](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10380/can-bonded-rabbits-die-of-loneliness), are all very real risks.

You have badly mismanaged your rabbit warren, and have failed to do basic research before starting a breeding program.  That is what is wrong.

Comment: I think you haven't even read my question properly. I clearly mentioned in the question 
I keep both buck and doe in separate hutches/cages." So kindly read properly before passing any judgement Thanks.

Comment: My Question was so simple that sooner I felt that Doe is pregnant which she wasn't and was building nest might be due to false pregnancy I separated her and its been more than 16 days she built the nest. The babies was supposed to be there by now if she was really pregnant.

Comment: And your comments clearly say you left the buck in with the doe for several days. So which is it?

Comment: Even the question link you shared above specifies that you should remove buck before the delivery of litters. I have removed him 15 days in advance already :)

Comment: But you did leave him in with the doe, for nearly two weeks.  During that time he presumably mated her at daily, probably several times per day. Each of those encounters potentially resulting in new ovation and pregnancy. this causes significant biologically difficulties. Additionally during that two weeks, the two either formed a bond or did not, in either case the physiological trauma is sufficient to put both a risk for their lives.    The doe and the buck should not be left unsupervised, and should be separated as soon as mating has completed (with 2 events often recommended as optimal)

Comment: Sometimes does don't accept the buck for mating then Its the practice to give them time and leave them in the cage. So she accepts him overnight.

Comment: That is not a [practice for pet rabbits](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10449/introducing-male-rabbit-to-girl-rabbit/10450#10450) this is a site for pets.

Comment: @Waqas Unless you have some reference, that suggests that leaving an intact buck unsupervised with a doe overnight or for days is a recommended practice in the raising of pet rabbits I am going to vote to close this question as out of scope for site about pets. If you do have a reference post it in your question so it can be debunked.

Comment: Ok what is your suggestion if Doe isn't letting the buck to mate if you have been trying for weeks ??