# Two bundles of bunnies by one momma

Tags: rabbits

I thought, I had two girls because that's what I was told when I got them. Turns out one bunny was male. We didn't notice the babies till thire eyes where open. We found what one was the male and put him in his own cage. It's been two weeks since we found them. Today I found babies she just had to have less then 12hrs ago. Will the new bundle be okay with mom and the first bundle...do I take the first bundle out? Please, any information is greatly appreciated! I haven't been able to find an answer just looking up stuff. TIA

Comment: When did you get them? Could be both were pregnant when you bought them? Could you make a photo of the bundles each? Have a bundle with its mum in a small cage leads to agression of the mum. In nature she wants to stay away the bundle to not attract predators. So please give her enough space to do so. I will link some questions in the next comments which may help

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31540/my-rabbit-isn-t-feeding-her-baby-what-should-i-do/31543#31543

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27932/accidentally-bonded-and-bred-sibling-rabbits-what-do-i-do-will-the-doe-ever/27935#27935

Comment: Also have a look to this german website's photos for ideas how you can give enough space to your rabbits https://kaninchenwiese.de/haltung/wohnungshaltung/innenhaltung-fotos/