# So I am looking into getting a young rabbit but i have 4 cats

Tags: cats, rabbits, adoption, bonding

So i want a young rabbit and i have 4 cats and one of them is 2 years old and is very hyper he loves to jump and play and attacks the other 3 cats. Should I get a 3 month old bunny with a cat like him? If I can find a spot that would not be outside and would be out of his reach would that work?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would say no. That sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. Cats are instinctive hunters and on very rare occasions 'play nice' with prey animals such as rats, birds, guinea pigs etc.

Unless you have 4 extremely gentle mannered cats, which is highly unlikely, I believe their presence and interest in the little furry new thing would, quite literally, scare a baby rabbit to death.

Comment: I once had an outdoor cat who regularly came home with a rabbit to feed to her kittens..

Answer (score 1):

A young rabbit is not going to fit well into the family you describe.  Cats and rabbits do well together, see related [What should we look for in a kitty companion for our rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2219) But a young bunny and an aggressive cat are not going to be a good match.

Optimally your rabbit should have access to as much of the house as the cats do. See [Can house rabbits have free access to the whole house all the time?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1320) though some people limit bunnies to just [one room for any number of reasons.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8122)

You will need the right rabbit to fit into the existing family of cats you describe.  I would suggest an adult rabbit of 2 plus years of age, probably a medium to large rabbit like an [English Spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Spot). Rabbits have different personalities and you will want one that is not timid.  Depending on where you live the local shelter may have [Rabbit Romps or something simular](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/978/why-do-rabbits-leave-droppings-at-the-romp) that will let you assess the personality of the rabbit, before you adopt.  Rabbits from a shelter tend to be older, litter box trained and spayed or neutered as part of the adoption process.

We have several posts about [rabbits & cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits+cats) that will help you a lot as you make your decisions.

**IMPORTANT: Always have a place that the cat can get away from the rabbit.** It is not possible to have an area where the cats can't get to the rabbit. For the most part this is not an issue.  You will have supervised the introductions and formed the relationship, before leaving them alone together. Rabbits are generally more territorial and demanding of attention then cats.

This leads to situations where the cat is not providing the attention that rabbit thinks it is entitled to, the rabbit can be aggressive to the cat, the cat than wants a place it can have some alone time, until it is ready for more time with the rabbit.  Rabbits tend not to go higher then then couch or bed, and leaps to areas at or greater then a counter are unusual.  There should be a high shelf, cat tree, or someplace for the cat to be able to be safe from the rabbit.