# Aggression between desexed male rabbits

Tags: behavior, rabbits, aggression

My sister's housemate recently got two male desexed rabbits.

They claw and bite at each other, more so one on the other, to the point of bloody ears. It's so bad, they've had to be separated into different hutches.

I've never heard of this before (aside from the [killer rabbit on Monty Python - WARNING NSFW](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=0Fk6-3f_mqU)).

Is this usual behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is completely normal.

Gender of the bunnies has no bearing on the outcome.  Desexing at least 30 days before attempting to bond is important. Each bunny has a personality, personality conflicts between rabbits tend to be the rule.

Bunnies are extremely territorial, the fights and damage is often more severe then you would expect with cats or dogs.  The bunny in the photos below was housed with several others, you can see that ears have been chewed off, eyebrows are missing their noses are misshapen. Some rabbits in this rescue died.

After the rescue many of these bunnies made friends and now live happily together. Others bonded with new friends, some remain unbonded and live alone with their people.

[image]
[image]

Related [Do rabbits fight each other to the death?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15722/do-rabbits-fight-each-other-to-the-death)

Making rabbits live happily together is hard work, it can take months and still not succeed.  In other cases, a couple of weeks will result in a successful bonding.   There is an article at [Rabbit.org about bonding](https://rabbit.org/faq-bonding-multiple-rabbits/)

We have a couple of posts about [rabbit bonding here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonding+rabbits)

Comment: I was hoping you'd see this. Thanks, a horrific revelation. So much for the cute bunny image. One of the bunnies scratched the owners arms when she was trying to separate them