# How can I mark my own territory and communicate this to my pet rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, communication, territory

So we got a holland lop rabbit a few weeks ago second hand from another couple. 
He's been great so far, but I've been reading online about communicating with my rabbit by mimicking his own behavior, such as communicating insult by walking up to him, taking a step back, then turning my back on him, similar to what he does to me when i do something he doesn't like and he demands an apology in this way.

I also read that rabbits understand territory in 3 categories, their own personal space shared with a mate and only close personal friends - public space, shared by all, and territory owned by someone else. 
I wonder, how can I mark my own territory (such as my bedroom) so he will understand this is my territory, and be less likely to wander in there and get in to things. 
Rabbits mark by peeing or pooping, I'm certainly not going to take a dump on my carpet.. lol - so how can I mark my territory in a way he'll understand and respect? it's easy to be a human about it, consistently remove him from a room etc.. and he'll eventually learn "if i go in there, I'm gonna get kicked out, so i wont go in there" - but I want to do it in a way where his natural instincts kick in and tell him "this is someone else's territory" - If i can get that point across by marking it as my own in a way he understands, coupled with normal training techniques (removing him from the room) he'll get the point

does anyone have any advice? I've actually had some success curbing annoying behavior be acting insulted like he does to me, but I'd really like to learn more about the territory stuff

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting your information about rabbit behavior. Some of it disagrees with my research and experience.  If you could include links or references to those sources that would be great.  We have several existing posts, a couple to start with are [limiting access](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8122) & [Territory](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/514)